# Difference between using virtual functions and redefining

Tags: c++

What's the difference between redefining and using a virtual function? Don't they serve the same purpose? You are allowing objects of a derived class to call their own versions of a function by the same name in both cases..so where is the distinction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The only way to take advantage of the polymorphism in C++ is via virtual functions and pointers (and references). The virtual keyword will tell the compiler to allocate a virtual function table where to look when deciding what version of the virtual function to call when dealing with pointer to the base class with a dynamic type that is of a child class.

**How does polymorphism work in C++**

Let's take a simple example:

```
class A { public: virtual void eat() { std::cout << "Class A" << std::endl; }
class B : public A {};
class C : public B { virtual void eat() { std::cout << "Class C" << std::endl; }
```

*Note: the virtual keyword could be omitted after the first function/method definition.*

The following:

```
A a; B b; C c;
A* ptrA = &a; A* ptrB = &b; A* ptrC = &c;
ptrA->eat();
ptrB->eat();
ptrC->eat();
```

will print:

```
Class A
Class A
Class C
```

If we wouldn't have declared the function `eat` virtual, the output would have simply been:

```
Class A
Class A
Class A
```

Answer (score 6):

An example says it best:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual void f1() { cout << "Class A" << endl; }
  void f2() { cout << "Class A" << endl; }
  virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void f1() { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
  void f2() { cout << "Class B" << endl; }
  virtual ~B(){}
};

int main()
{
  A *a = new B;
  a->f1();
  a->f2();
}
```

...

```
$ ./override 
Class B
Class A
```

You can see that when we reference the instance of B, `f1()` still calls `B`'s version, but `f2()` calls `A`'s.

When you declare a function virtual, you are saying that when we call it we should use the vtable to look up the right version of the function to call, and so you will always get the most derived version of the function, even if you reference it as an ancestor type. Without virtual, it will simply use the definition in the type you are referencing it as.

Answer (score 3):

The distinction is when you have a reference or pointer to the base class. A call to a virtual function will call the most-derived version while a call to a normal function will call the base-class version.

If you're using a variable directly or a reference or pointer to the most-derived class, there is no practical difference.

Answer (score -1):

But why

```
A* ptrA = &a; A* ptrB = &b; A* ptrC = &c;
```

Instead of

```
A* ptrA = &a; B* ptrB = &b; C* ptrC = &c;
```

With the second version, the `eat()` method can simply be redefined for each derived class, without the need for `virtual`, right?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).